# Don't send email notification when ACL modified for Google Doc

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I'm trying to find the Java way of doing:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#email_notifications_of_acl_changes

`POST https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/document:12345/acl?send-notification-emails=false`

So that no emails are sent when an ACL is added/modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform the same task using the newer Drive API which has a complete Java sample at https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert.

You have to use the `setSendNotificationEmails` method of `Drive.Permissions.Insert`.

Comment: Unfortunately, my application is heavily based on the Google Document List API. It would be impossible to rewrite it at this late stage. Could you possibly advise how to do this with the Google Document List API.

Comment: Any way of doing this using the Google Documents List API for an existing application. The Google Drive API is not an option.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Java client library for the Documents List API doesn't expose that option.